# PHP какой файл отвечает за вывод меню

Tags: php, меню

Здравствуйте! Помогите определить, какой из указанных в данном коде файлов может отвечать за вывод верхнего меню на html-странице.

Я сеошник, знаю html/css/ немножко js. А сайт достался самописный на пхп, программист пропал куда-то, что редактировать не пойму. Страница полностью программная, статичного кода нет совсем.

Мне нужно пункты верхнего меню (они списком выводятся в хтмл сразу после открывающего body и логотипа) обернуть в заголовки. В принципе, с простейшими командами пхп, вроде echo, я, наверное, разберусь. Подскажите, в каком файле их искать. Спасибо.

В html блок меню имеет класс menu. Здесь такого не вижу.

```
<?define('core',true);header('Content-type: text/html; 
charset="utf-8"');include('common/db.php');include
('common/pathfinder.php');if ($_COOKIE['uid'] || $_POST['nic']) 
{include('common/user.php');}include('common/settings.php');include
('common/client.php');include('common/functions.php');include
('common/getpage.php');include('common/zones.php');if ($zone[1]) 
{foreach ($zone[1] as $inc_id=>$incname) {include
($incname.'.php');}}?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<?if ($zone[2]) {?>
<head><?foreach ($zone[2] as $inc_id=>$incname) {include
($incname.'.php');}?>
</head>

<?}?>
<body class="scheme<?=$page_scheme ?>">
<div class="all"><?if ($zone[3]) {?><div class="roof<? if 

($page_id==29) { ?> searchpagetop<? } ?>">
<?foreach ($zone[3] as $inc_id=>$incname) {include

($incname.'.php');}?>

</div>
<?}?>

<div class="basis">
<?if ($zone[4]) {?>

<div class="top"><?foreach ($zone[4] as $inc_id=>$incname) {include

($incname.'.php');}?>
</div><?}?>

<div class="main">
<?if ($zone[5]) {?>
<div class="left"><?foreach ($zone[5] as $inc_id=>$incname) 

{include($incname.'.php');}?></div><?}?>

<div class="content" id="page-<?=$page_id ?>">
<?include 
('contents/'.$page_type.'.php');if ($zone[6]) {foreach ($zone[6] as 

$inc_id=>$incname) {include($incname.'.php');}}?>
</div>

<?if ($zone[7]) {?><div class="right">
<?foreach ($zone[7] as $inc_id=>$incname) {include

($incname.'.php');}?>
</div><?}?>
</div><?if ($zone[8]) {?>

<div class="footer"><?foreach ($zone[8] as $inc_id=>$incname) 

{include($incname.'.php');}?></div><?}?></div><?if ($zone[9]) {?

><div class="hid"><?foreach ($zone[9] as $inc_id=>$incname) 

{include($incname.'.php');}?></div><?}?></div><? if ($uid) { ?><div 

class="admlabel" style="position:fixed; top:0px; left:20px; 

padding:10px; background-color:#ffffff; box-shadow:2px 2px 7px 

#777777; border-radius:0px 0px 8px 8px; z-index:100;"><a 

href="/edit/pages/<?=$page_id ?>/">Редактировать 

страницу</a></div><? } ?></body></html>
```

Вот содержание запрошенного файла:

```
    <?$module_types_q=mysql_query("select * from `wa_modules` where `off`=0 
order by `id`");while ($module_types_row=mysql_fetch_array($module_types_q)) 
{$moduleid=$module_types_row['id'];$module_file[$moduleid]=
$module_types_row['filename'];$module_param[$moduleid]=$module_types_row

['param'];if ($module_types_row['type']==1) {$module_folder
[$moduleid]='modules/';}if ($module_types_row['type']==2) {$module_folder
[$moduleid]='contents/menu/';}if ($module_types_row['type']==3) 
{$module_folder[$moduleid]='contents/form/';}if ($module_types_row
['type']==4) {$module_folder
[$moduleid]='contents/';}}$zones_select_q=mysql_query("select * from 
`wa_schemepoints` where `scheme`='$page_scheme' order by `order`");while 
($zones_select_row=mysql_fetch_array($zones_select_q)){$zone_num=
$zones_select_row['zone'];$zone_file=$module_folder[$zones_select_row
['module']].$module_file[$zones_select_row['module']];$zone_inc_id=
$zones_select_row['id'];$zone[$zone_num][$zone_inc_id]=$zone_file;
$zoneparam[$zone_inc_id]=$module_param[$zones_select_row['module']];}?>
```

Comment: Какой-то. Это у вас, скорее всего, фреймворк какой-то. Соответственно попробуйте изучить документацию по нему, так как захардкоживание костылей может привести к очень неприятным и неисправимым последствиям.

Comment: нет, сайт самописный (2007 года создания, тогда, вроде фреймворки не были особенно распространены). Во всяком случае, мне однозначно при трудоустройстве говорили, что я не буду непосредственно с кодом работать, ибо не разберусь никогда. А, вот, приходится

Comment: Ну тогда ПКМ по пункту меню в браузере, смотреть разметку, ID-шники, классы и тупо искать по всем файлам, где оно встречается

Comment: в хтмл - чистый хтмл.div class='menu'. Всё. Ну, и на том спасибо. Завтра еще раз пересмотрю все файлы, перечисленные в начале этого кода. Может, что и найду "методом тыка"

Comment: Не "все файлы перечисленные...", а поиск по содержимому всех файлов сайта на предмет `class='menu'`. PHP довольно гибкий язык и подключение файлов может быть сделано абсолютно не очевидным образом.

Answer (score 1):

Судя по коду есть некий массив $zone. Сайт поделен на зоны, и в каждой зоне есть названия файлов. Взгляните в данном файле :

> /common/zones.php.

Там в скорее всего в элементе массива 3 или 4 может быть название файла меню. 
Если есть возможность показать сам файл **zones.php**, то могу точно сказать)

Comment: Спасибо. Приложила

Comment: В директории **/contents/menu/** должны храниться меню. Можно попробовать найти в базе данных, в таблице.